# Why does tikz produce output in plain tex when it does not in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plain-tex

This simple document `testlatex.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

when running `latex testlatex` produces `No pages of output.`

But this document `testtex.tex`

```
\input tikz
\end
```

when running `tex testtex` produces `Output written on testtex.dvi (1 page, 3312 bytes).`

I would expect the second one to not produce any output either, why are they different?

Comment: Interesting. First I thought it may be because different engines are involved (in currently popular TeX distributions, `latex` runs pdfTeX, as we can see with `latex --version`, while `tex` runs something closer to Knuth's TeX). But this not the reason, because the question is reproducible with `pdflatex` and `pdftex` (the latter produces a blank page containing only the page number 1). (Similarly, what `dvitype testtex.dvi` shows is that the DVI file contains some PGF specials, some movements, then the page number.) My current guess is that it's because LaTeX uses a different output routine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer:

- `\input tikz` loads the file `tikz.tex`, while `\usepackage{tikz}` loads the file `tikz.sty`. Those files are different, and in turn load different files.
- In particular, `pgfrcs.tex` has `\input pgfutil-plain.def` while `pgfrcs.sty` has `\input pgfutil-latex.def`
- The code in `pgfutil-plain.def` has `\openout` which results in the creation of a whatsit node (and hence “output”, and the DVI file), while the code in `pgfutil-latex.def` piggybacks on LaTeX's aux file, which does `\immediate\openout` instead.

### How to isolate the issue

(This section just describes how the above was arrived at.)

This is what I tried. By looking in the log file (or using `kpsewhich`), we can find the specific file that is being input, in the two cases. We can copy that file over to the current directory, and start editing it into something minimal: remove as much from it as possible, while the files still compile and exhibit the difference. They will probably input other files; copy them as well and repeat.

By doing this recursively, I was able to reduce the two cases to the following:

```
% tex testtex.tex                        
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=tex)
(./testtex.tex (./tikz.tex (./pgf.tex (./pgfcore.tex (./pgfsys.tex (./pgfrcs.tex (./pgfutil-common.tex) (./pgfutil-plain.def)) (./pgfsys.code.tex))))) [1] )
Output written on testtex.dvi (1 page, 196 bytes).
Transcript written on testtex.log.
```

where most of the files simply `\input` the others as indicated in the log line above. The nontrivial files (after minimizing) are `pgfrcs.tex`:

```
\input pgfutil-common.tex
\input pgfutil-plain.def
```

`pgfutil-common.tex`:

```
\catcode`\@=11\relax

% Which format is loaded?
\newif\ifpgfutil@format@is@latex
\newif\ifpgfutil@format@is@plain

\let\pgfutil@aux@read@hook=\relax

\newtoks\pgfutil@everybye
```

`pgfutil-plain.def`:

```
\pgfutil@format@is@plaintrue

% The aux files, needed for reading back coordinates
\def\pgfutil@aux@read@hook{
  \csname newwrite\endcsname\pgfutil@auxout
  \csname openout\endcsname\pgfutil@auxout\jobname.pgf
}
```

`pgfsys.code.tex`:

```
% Read aux file in plain and context mode:
\pgfutil@aux@read@hook
```

### Summary

The file `pgfrcs.tex` has `\input pgfutil-plain.def` while the file `pgfrcs.sty` has `\input pgfutil-latex.def`, and those two `.def` files contain substantial differences.

In particular, in the plain TeX case, at minimum we're running the following:

```
\catcode`\@=11\relax

%%%%%%%%%% From pgfutil-plain.def < pgfrcs.tex < pgfsys.tex < pgfcore.tex < pgf.tex < tikz.tex
% The aux files, needed for reading back coordinates
\def\pgfutil@aux@read@hook{
  \csname newwrite\endcsname\pgfutil@auxout
  \csname openout\endcsname\pgfutil@auxout\jobname.pgf
}

%%%%%%%%%% From pgfsys.code.tex < pgfsys.tex < pgfcore.tex < pgf.tex < tikz.tex
\pgfutil@aux@read@hook

\end
```

and that's already enough to result in the creation of the `.dvi` file.

(The answer of @egreg explains the further contents of the `.dvi` file—the PGF-related specials, that are needed to go into the PDF dictionary on every page—but not why a page is shipped out in the first place. To check this, we can simply remove the line `\csname openout\endcsname\pgfutil@auxout\jobname.pgf` from `pgfutil-plain.def`, and make absolutely no other changes, and see that your original `testtex.tex` does not result in the creation of a DVI file, even though the stuff that @egreg showed is still present in `pgfutil-plain.def`.)

What the above shows is that we can find the difference already between:

```
\input pgfsys
\end
```

(in plain TeX) and (in LaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfsys}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Also, here's an even more minimal plain-TeX file that results in the creation of a DVI file:

```
\newwrite\outfile
\openout\outfile\jobname.pgf
\end
```

In the LaTeX case (in `pgfutil-latex.def`), there is a similar `\AtBeginShipout` and everything, but there's no `\openout`. Instead, it piggybacks on LaTeX's `\@auxout`. That one is defined, in `latex.ltx` (the definition of `\document`), using `\immediate\openout\@mainaux\jobname.aux`. And we can see that simply adding `\immediate` to our earlier minimal file does not result in the creation of a DVI file:

```
\newwrite\outfile
\immediate\openout\outfile\jobname.pgf
\end
```

Comment: But I feel I'm still left asking why.
Is it a bug that it's done this way in plain?
Is it a temporary fix put in because it would be too much work to do it properly in plain?
Is it possible to fix it so that it works the same in plain as in latex?
What other differences are there between running tikz with plain vs latex?

Comment: @nadder (Answering backwards) • Looking at the many differences I found while trying to answer this, I would imagine there are dozens or hundreds of minor differences between TikZ in plain vs LaTeX. Often in LaTeX when something is needed the code can just require some corresponding package, while in plain either an equivalent plain-compatible package is used or some code is manually written for that part. (As here, for aux file, which is in LaTeX but was done in an ad-hoc way for plain.) I imagine that when some significant user-visible difference is noticed, they'd fix the code to be closer.

Comment: @nadder (To emphasize, when running TikZ with plain a `.pgf` file is created, while with LaTeX an `.aux` file is created (in case of nonempty output). This is a user-visible difference but wouldn't be considered a bug.) • I don't off-hand foresee a problem with changing the `\openout` in `pgfutil-plain.def` to `\immediate\openout`… maybe someone just forgot the `\immediate` or didn't see why it's necessary. (It probably doesn't make a difference except for a document with no output, as here.) We could add `\immediate` in our local copy of `pgfutil-plain.def`, and try lots of TikZ examples.

Comment: a new question arise here, why `\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\outfile
\openout\outfile\jobname.pgf
\begin{document}
\end{document}` don't shipout any page?

Comment: @touhami Good question! Maybe you can ask it as a new question… my guess is that it has something to do with LaTeX's output routine: the whatsit is indeed created and passed to the output routine, but in LaTeX's case it is then thrown away and no shipout happens. But I haven't looked into it, so not sure.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR [done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423643/why-does-openout-produce-output-in-plain-tex-when-it-does-not-in-latex)

Answer (score 5):

At some point, `\pgfutil@abe` is executed, which issues `\unhbox`.

Here's the justification:

```
272 \AtBeginShipout{% 
273   \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\vbox{% 
274     \setbox0=\hbox{% 
275       \begingroup   
276                 % the boxes \pgfutil@abe ("every page") and \pgfutil@abb ("current page")
277                 % are used to generate pdf objects / dictionaries which are
278                 % required for the graphics which are somewhere in the "real"
279                 % page content.
280                 % BUT: these pdf objects MUST NOT be affected by text layout
281                 % shifts! Consequently, we have to undo \hoffset and \voffset
282                 % (which are h/v shifts to the page layout).
283                 %
284                 % Note that this of importance for shadings. To be more
285                 % specific: try out shadings with standalone (which uses
286                 % \hoffset) and with xdvipdfmx (which appears to be more
287                 % fragile than pdflatex) - they break unless we undo \hoffset
288                 % and \voffset.
289                 \ifdim\hoffset=0pt \else \hskip-\hoffset\fi
290         \pgfutil@abe 
291         \unhbox\pgfutil@abb 
292         \pgfutil@abc 
293         \global\let\pgfutil@abc\pgfutil@empty 
294                 \ifdim\hoffset=0pt \else \hskip+\hoffset\fi
295       \endgroup 
296     }%
```

Comment: For completeness: why does this happen in plain TeX but not in LaTeX? It's because `\AtBeginShipout` works differently I guess?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That's quite possible

Comment: This (explains the contents of the DVI file but) turns out not to be the reason actually: the reason is `\openout` (in `pgfutil-plain.def`) versus `\immediate\openout` (in LaTeX).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR In LaTeX no `.pgf` file is created, because the standard `.aux` file is used.

Comment: Yes right, that's what I found (mentioned as “piggyback” in my answer), and that's what I meant by “in LaTeX” (meant `latex.ltx`, specifically from `ltfiles.dtx`). The standard `.aux` file in LaTeX is created with `\immediate\openout`, while the `.pgf` file is created with `\openout`. Not sure why that is, though.