# Why does \openout produce output in plain tex when it does not in latex?

Tags: tex-core, output, write, output-routine, shipout

This is a follow up question of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422845/why-does-tikz-produce-output-in-plain-tex-when-it-does-not-in-latex). Why this plain code (from [shreevatsar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48/shreevatsar)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422845/why-does-tikz-produce-output-in-plain-tex-when-it-does-not-in-latex/422893#422893))

```
\newwrite\outfile
\openout\outfile\jobname.out
\end
```

produce a page but this (equivalent) latex code does not?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newwrite\outfile
\openout\outfile\jobname.out
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert a `\showlists` just before the end

```
\makeatletter
\showoutput


\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
     \if@filesw
       \immediate\closeout\@mainaux
       \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo
       \let\@newl@bel\@testdef
       \@tempswafalse
       \makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux
     \fi
     \@dofilelist
     \ifdim \font@submax >\fontsubfuzz\relax
       \@font@warning{Size substitutions with differences\MessageBreak
                  up to \font@submax\space have occurred.\@gobbletwo}%
     \fi
     \@defaultsubs
     \@refundefined
     \if@filesw
       \ifx \@multiplelabels \relax
         \if@tempswa
           \@latex@warning@no@line{Label(s) may have changed.
               Rerun to get cross-references right}%
         \fi
       \else
         \@multiplelabels
       \fi
     \fi
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\showlists\@@end}




\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\outfile
\openout\outfile\jobname.out
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

You see

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\write-{}
\openout3=file.out
\write-{}

prevdepth 0.0

! OK.
\enddocument ...dgroup \deadcycles \z@ \showlists 
                                                  \@@end 
l.47 \end{document}

?
```

That is the write node is left on its own.

Essentially the implicit `\clearpage` at the end of the document has cycled round and knows there is no height in the current page and it has no floats to add, so it stops.

---

Conversely the plain output routine is

```
\def\plainoutput{\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline\pagebody\makefootline}%
```

It is not doing any tests to re-insert floats (Plain TeX uses the `\insert` mechanism so doesn't handle floats "by hand" the way LaTeX does) so it always ships out something whenever the output routine is called.